# how can I easily shift my SSIS package from SQL Server to Oracle?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, business-intelligence, msbi

I have developed 25 SSIS packages with SQL Server backend. Now my requirements have changed so that the SSIS package stays the same but the database which I use should shift from SQL server to Oracle Database,

How I can change the DB in my SSIS package from SQL Server to Oracle?

Comment: I do not quite understand what you mean. Do you want to run your SSIS-Packages on an Oracle-DB from now on? Do you know what SSIS stands for?

Comment: Hi Johannes, Yeah, Previously I used to run them on SQL Server but now on I want to run SSIS packages on an Oracle-DB. How can I do that? Is there a way to switch between databases ? Or I have to start my package designing from scratch?

Comment: Wait, so is your SQL Server box going away? As long as you still have a server with the appropriate SQL Server edition, you can run SSIS packages that access Oracle dbs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I do not think, there is a way to do that. SSIS stands for SQL Server Integration Services for a reason :)

Oracle does have a similar framework called *Golden Gate*:
http://www.oracle.com/us/products/middleware/data-integration/goldengate/overview/index.html

I guess, you would have to start from scratch. But since you already have got the concepts - assuming your SSIS-Packages are working - to create your Data Integration Services, you will "only" have to get familiar with Golden Gate.

Answer (score 0):

Are you kidding? This can be solved. All you have to do is edit the packages to use the source and destination as your oracle databases. The rest remains the same. It also depends on how the data is processed internally in packages.

If your packages are using any transformations in Data Flow and if the data flow is using any sql commands then you need to think of that too. Also, if your control flow is using any SQL task then also you need to think of that.

You can edit a single package and try converting it to Oracle. SSIS can treat Oracle data as well, this is not a limitation of SSIS.

Comment: -1 for not reading the question and the related comments thoroughly. Golden Gate and SSIS are two similar but still different technologies. But yes, if your approach to an unknown technology is simply to copy paste everything with 25 complete and running packages (!), then go ahead

Comment: @Johannes I don't agree with the -1. OP is ostensibly asking about changing the db being accessed in the package from SQL Server to Oracle. If OP still has the capability to run an SSIS package, then vaibhav's answer is still applicable.

Comment: As you've read above, I asked the OP whether he has to migrate from an SSIS-Server to an Oracle-Server (with something like Golden Gate). He said "Yes", so my downvote and my answer are still valid. It might be that he just wanted to change his SSIS-packages' sources and / or destinations, which would be just trivial...